# Indicate variable values from side-effects with Python type hinting

Tags: python, python-typing

With type-hinting in Python 3.9, once an `isinstance` call is made in an if-statement, the typing interpreter knows the variable type. For example:

```
if isinstance(value, int):
    value += 1  # <-- known to be an int
```

However if you wanted to do some sort of additional validation, then the typing interpreter can easily get confused. For example:

```
def is_positive_int(value:Any)->bool:
    return isinstance(value, int) and value>=0

if is_positive_int(value):
    value += 1  # <-- NOT known to be an int
```

Is it possible to mimic the behavior of, in this case, `isinstance` and instruct the type-interpreter to treat a variable as a specific type depending on the return of `is_positive_int`?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm using 3.9, and I added a note to that in the question

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeGuard?

Comment: How are you assessing whether "it is known to be an int"?

Comment: The assessment is made by tools such as mypy (e.g. in a CICD pipeline), or Pylance (in VSCode)

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yes, TypeGuard is what I'm looking for. Thank you for pointing that out! But it looks like it is "New in Python 3.10", is there something equivalent for 3.9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the implementation of [PEP 647](https://peps.python.org/pep-0647/) in Python 3.10, you can use `typing.TypeGuard` for this:

> Using `-> TypeGuard` tells the static type checker that for a given
> function:
>
> 1. The return value is a boolean.
> 2. If the return value is `True`, the type of its argument is the type inside `TypeGuard`.

In your case that would be:

```
def is_positive_int(value: Any) -> TypeGuard[int]:
    return isinstance(value, int) and value >= 0
```

This has been backported to Python 3.6-3.9 via [`typing_extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/).